# Setting an ActionScript List border

Tags: list, actionscript, border

Is there a way to place a border around an ActionScript List?  (I mean a border that I can see, such as a red border of one pixel width.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  yourList.setStyle("borderStyle", "solid");
  youtList.setStyle("borderColor", "red");
```